# CiviMail: "DB error" alert pop-up

Tags: civimail, joomla, 4.6.2

During creation of a mailing with 10k contacts, frequently, getting black pop-up alerting "DB error" with no other information. Please advise.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';  
+-----------------+-------+  
| Variable_name   | Value |  
+-----------------+-------+  
| max_connections | 200   |  
+-----------------+-------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**PHP Built On:**   Linux host.alcoholjustice.org 2.6.32-042stab094.8 #1 SMP   Tue Dec 16 20:36:56 MSK 2014 i686
**Database Version:**   5.5.42-cll
**Database Collation:**     latin1_swedish_ci
**PHP Version:**    5.3.27
**Web Server:**     LiteSpeed
**WebServer to PHP Interface:**     litespeed
**Joomla! Version:**    Joomla! 3.4.1 Stable [ Ember ] 21-March-2015 20:30 GMT
**Joomla! Platform Version:**   Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT

Comment: Do you get any additional info when you enable debugging (**Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**)?  Could you post (or link to) a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Today, on the Joomla Demo site, I have uploaded a list of ~2000 fake email addresses, placed them in a group and proceeded to start a bulk email and receiving the same db error pop-up message.

Comment: And, I am not able to get debugging to work in this view. I've turned it on and used the Smarty extension. The AJAX guts do not appear.

Comment: Here is backtrace from ConfigAndLogs showing timing out:

Comment: Backtrace: http://pastebin.com/gns2Wkfd

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this could be the same as or related to issue [CRM-16277](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16277), which has been fixed for 4.6.3.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. I will wait for 4.6.3 and test again.

Comment: Applied patch pre-4.6.3 that fixed problem but now it continues to send bulk mailing despite full job showing completion in report.

Comment: If you applied the patch and are experiencing this, to stop the process: `1. Open command line (CLI) terminal (SSH, console, etc.) 2. Type "ps aux |grep cli" (or whatever script you call in the cronjob) 3. Note the ProcessID (PID) number and confirm this is for the exact process that applies to the mailing or running cronjob 4. Type "kill (PID)" 5. Go back to the CiviMail report and keep refreshing browser to confirm it stops sending.